# Saving input/textbox without submit button on stopped typing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

Just seeing if there's any best practice stuff on saving text inputs without a submit button. I've got this working fine with a delay when input is stopped using Jquery (on MVC site Ajax to Controller) but this still keeps posting data when a user waits to continue typing etc.

I'd ideally like a way of determining that a user has finished updating text within a textbox/text field without the need for a physical save button.

Is there a client side library/function I can use or even cache with writes on the server side & then write to db after a delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you are determining the user has finished updating the text. Since you don't want to post data after delay then, I guess, the only way here is to check when the user changes focus from the text input field. In that case you can use `onfocusout` event.

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="postData(value)" />
```

Comment: This is a good solution... but would be good to also capture the values if the user closes the browser/navigates away from the site. Otherwise they could fill out the textarea/description box & assume it's saved & navigate elsewhere.